# Send HTTP streaming request in perl

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I want to send xml request using HTTP streaming protocol . where transfer-encoding is "chunked". Currently i am using LWP::UserAgent to send the xml transaction.

```
my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $starttime = time();
my $response = $userAgent->request(POST $url,
Content_Type => 'application/xml',
Transfer_Encoding => 'Chunked',
Content => $xml);


print "Response".Dumper($response);
```

But i am getting http status code `411 Length Required`. Which means "client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request without a defined "

How we can handle this while sending a request in chunked ?

Comment: Does `$xml` contain XML or a chunked message as you promised?

Comment: From looking at the source, LWP::Protocol (used by LWP::UserAgent) will automatically chunk the response for you if 1) You didn't provide a Content-Length header, and 2) you provided a subroutine reference instead of a string as the message.

Comment: $xml has the complete xml

Comment: @ikegami so i didn't understand , what needs to be changed here ?

Comment: Not sure, thus the lack of an answer. Start by removing that Transfer Encoding header, then figure out how to pass a callback to LWP::Protocol, and what the callback should look like. Might be as simple as `Content => sub { length($xml) ? substr($xml, 0, length($xml), '') : undef }` Working on my on stuff right now.

Comment: If that callback works, it returns the entire XML document as the first chunk. That's cause it makes no sense to use a chunked transfer when you already have the complete response body handy.

Comment: Possible alternative is to use Mojo::UserAgent: https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Guides::Cookbook#Streaming-request

Answer (score 2):

LWP::UserAgent's API isn't designed to send a stream, but it is able to do so with minimal hacking.

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST );
use LWP::UserAgent        qw( );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

# Don't provide any content.
my $request = POST('http://stackoverflow.org/junk',
   Content_Type => 'application/xml',
);

# POST() insists on adding a Content-Length header.
# We need to remove it to get a chunked request.
$request->headers->remove_header('Content-Length');

# Here's where we provide the stream generator.
my $buffer = 'abc\n';
$request->content(sub {
   return undef if !length($buffer);                # Return undef when done.
   return substr($buffer, 0, length($buffer), '');  # Return a chunk of data otherwise.
});

my $response = $ua->request($request);
print($response->status_line);
```

Using a proxy (Fiddler), we can see this does indeed send a chunked request:

[image: Screenshot of proxy showing a chunked request was used]

---

There's no point in using a chunked request if you already have the entire document handy like in the example you gave. Instead, let's say wanted to upload the output of some external tool as it produced its output. To do that, you could use the following:

```
open(my $pipe, '-|:raw', 'some_tool');
$request->content(sub {
   my $rv = sysread($pipe, my $buf, 64*1024);
   die $! if !defined($rv);
   return undef if !$rv;
   return $buf;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i am getting http status code 411 Length Required.

Not all servers understand a request with a chunked payload even though this is standardized in HTTP/1.1 (but not in HTTP/1.0). For example nginx only supports chunking within a request since version 1.3.9 (2012), see [Is there a way to avoid nginx 411 Content-Length required errors?](https://serverfault.com/questions/164220/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-nginx-411-content-length-required-errors). If the server does not understand a request with chunked encoding there is nothing you can do from the client side, i.e. you simply cannot use chunked transfer encoding then. If you have control over the server make sure that the server actually supports it.

I've also never experienced browsers send such requests, probably since they cannot guarantee that the server will support such request. I've only seen mobile apps used where the server and app is managed by the same party and thus support for chunked requests can be guaranteed.

Comment: Re "*Not all servers understand a request with a chunked payload*", The OP said they didn't send a chunked body even though they sent the header claiming they did. That should definitely result in the obtained 411 error. There's no reason to believe the server doesn't support chunked in addition to this problem.

Comment: Re "*probably since they cannot guarantee that the server will support such request*", It's more likely that the reason they don't is that there's no reason for them to do so. Chunked is only needed when the size of the request isn't known beforehand, which basically never happens with a browser. When the client knows the size of the message beforehand, it's more efficient to use `Content-Length`.